# Sending an email to a User defined from a lookup?

Tags: apex, trigger, email, workflow, opportunity

I have a lookup field on our Opportunities, that pulls a User in our Organization.

I need to be able to email that specific user when the opportunity changes.

I can already figure out how to make a Workflow rule or Trigger get most of the information, but the trigger gets errors when trying to pull the email address, and the workflow rule doesn't have a dynamic way of doing this that I can find.

Does anyone know of an easier way to do this?

Right now I get an error where the OR Operator is.

```
Error: Compile Error: OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions at line 13 column 29



trigger EmailAssignedAM on Opportunity (after update) {

    Boolean email = false;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();

    User assignedAM = new User();

    for(Opportunity op : Trigger.new){
        opp = [SELECT Id, Assigned_AM__c, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :op.Id];
    }

    if( opp.Type = 'LMS' || opp.Type = 'LEARN - PM'){
        email = true;
    }

    if( opp.StageName = 'Closed Won' && email == true){

    assignedAM = [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :opp.Assigned_AM__c LIMIT 1];

    EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'New Account Added'];

                //Start the list of emails to send, per requirements
                List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

                //initiallize messaging method
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                //set object Id
                singleMail.setTargetObjectId(assignedAM.Id);

                //set template Id
                singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);

                //flag to false to stop inserting activity history
                singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

                //add mail
                emails.add(singleMail);

                //send mail
                Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty common use case for triggers. Post what you have and let us help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is a common oversight:

You have:

```
if( opp.Type = 'LMS' || opp.Type = 'LEARN - PM'){
    email = true;
}
```

It should be:

```
if( opp.Type == 'LMS' || opp.Type == 'LEARN - PM'){
    email = true;
}
```

The `==` operator is used to test for equality, not the `=` operator which is used for assignment

Look through the rest of your code for similar issues as in...

```
if( opp.StageName = 'Closed Won' && email == true){
```

Note that SOQL uses `=` for equality tests in the WHERE clause (just to confuse you and make programming more of a guild than perhaps it ought to be :-)

Answer (score 0):

You say your triggers gets errors, can you please post what you have and let us help you? It should be relatively simple and should look something like this:

```
trigger notifyRelatedUser on Opportunity (after update) {
    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        // Compose Messaging.SingleMailMessage here 
        // Add o.UserLookupField.Email to the list parameter of the setToAddresses method
        // Send email
    }
}
```

You will have to populate the fields on the message e.g. recipient, subject per the [Apex Messaging documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single).

Comment: Okay I've added my code along with what where I'm getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this all through workflow. I don't understand the need for a trigger. Just use "Related User" in the recipient type in the Email Alert.